# How to restrict quick file search

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to restrict the scope of the file search function (CMD + Shift + O on mac) to only search in a certain directory rather than the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html). You can specify the directory name when navigating:

[image: directory]